Remove Alphanumeric string and following character from end of the string in power BI
I want to remove alphanumeric string and all the following characters from the end of a string in column in power bi
example 1:
Input
/Chill/chill/batch/design/961057df-7a86-4159-a532-f6919175f478/version
Output
/Chill/chill/batch/design
example 2:
Input
/Chill/chill/batch/design/961057df-7a86-4159-a532-f6919175f478
Output
/Chill/chill/batch/design

= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each [a=Text.Start([Input],Text.PositionOfAny([Input],{"0".."9"})),
b=Text.PositionOf(a,"/",Occurrence.Last),
c=Text.Start(a,b)
][c])


= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each [a=Text.PositionOfAny([Input],{"0".."9"}),
b=Text.Start([Input],a),
c=Text.PositionOf(b,"/",Occurrence.Last),
d=Text.Start(b,c),
e= if a=-1 then [Input] else d
][e])



the string can contain words other then 'design' so this formula wont work

updated the answer. pls have a try

Thanks ... but for input /Chillers/chillers/batch/design/db59ebd2-1112-4ae2-be9f-9591ed3fcb75 it gives output as /Chillers/chillers/batch/design/d which is wrong as I want to remove the whole string  and also if no alphanumeric string is there then it gives error

updated again. pls have a try

Is it possible to copy the input string into output as it is if no alphaneumeric string is there in the end?

updated again， pls have a try
